# Ignore paths and Include path regex with migrating svn to git

Tags: regex, git, svn

I am working on migrating svn to git , with the structure.

Below is my svn path

http://scm.mysvnpath.corp/svn/com.my.svn

```
-branches
  -something
  -dontcare
-tags
  -india-1.0
  -usa-1.0
  -argentina-1.0
-trunk
  -india
  -usa
  -argentina
```

I want to migrate only india from tags and trunk.

I am using the below git commands

```
>git svn init http://scm.mysvnpath.corp/svn/com.my.svn --no-minimize-url --include-paths '(india)' --stdlayout --prefix 'svn/'

>git config svn.authorsfile authors.txt

>git svn fetch
```

But still it fetches usa and argentina from tags and trunk.

Not sure what is going wrong over here.

Thing I have already tried

```
>git svn init http://scm.mysvnpath.corp/svn/com.my.svn --no-minimize-url --include-paths 'india' --stdlayout --prefix 'svn/'

>git svn init http://scm.mysvnpath.corp/svn/com.my.svn --no-minimize-url --include-paths='india' --stdlayout --prefix 'svn/'

>git svn init http://scm.mysvnpath.corp/svn/com.my.svn --no-minimize-url --include-paths="india" --stdlayout --prefix 'svn/'
```

Thanks !